# Creating text files based on list of file names

Tags: python, bash

I have a list of file names in filenames.txt, that contains two or more files for a date like this:

```
foo_19990101_bar001.zip
foo_19990101_bar002.zip
foo_20000303_bar001.zip
foo_20000303_bar002.zip
foo_20000303_bar003.zip
foo_20021111_bar001.zip
foo_20021111_bar002.zip
...
```

I would like to create separate text files containing the file names for a single date, e.g. 19990101.txt would contain:

```
foo_19990101_bar001.zip
foo_19990101_bar002.zip
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far?

Comment: How is this related to python and bash?

Comment: You can make use of `sort`, it has a useful [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html)

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
    date="${line:4:8}"
    echo "$line" >> "${date}.txt"
done < filenames.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

this will create the new files with the name as the timestamp.

```
from collections import defaultdict

with open("filenames.txt") as fp:
    file_names = fp.read().split()
    
files_dict = defaultdict(list)

for name in file_names:
    timestamp = name.split("_", 2)[1]
    files_dict[timestamp].append(name)

for key, value in files_dict.items():
    with open(key, "w") as fp:
        fp.write("\n".join(value))
```